# Combining python 3.6 "f" formatting with latex formatting

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a latex expression in axes.text and I'm having difficulty telling python how to separate the {} from latex expressions from the {} from python formatting.

I ended up separating both expressions using latex format in one and python in another. I was wondering is there is a better, more "direct" way to do it.

Heres the code:

```
m, b, R2 = linregress(x, y)[:3]
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w", ec="0.5", alpha=0.9)
ax.text(-100, 0, '$\delta$ ${}^{18}O$ = ' + f'{m:{1}.{4}} x ' +
        '$\delta$ ${}^{2}H$ ' + f'+ ({b:{1}.{4}})' +
        '\n{${R}^{2}$} = ' + f'{R2:{1}.{3}}',
        ha="left", va="center", size=8, bbox=bbox_props)
```

Comment: Shouldn't double curly braces for the latex expressions work? Python evaluates those to single curly braces:`>>> f'{{x}}'` yields `'{x}'`